# MySQL: ¿Para qué sirve EXPLAIN en una consulta y cómo interpretar los resultados obtenidos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

He visto que en MySQL se puede ejecutar una consulta como lo hacemos normalmente:

```
SELECT 
     mis, columnas 
     FROM mitabla mt 
     INNER JOIN otratabla ot 
     ON mt.id = ot.id
```

Pero poniendo como primer comando `EXPLAIN` :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
     mis, columnas 
     FROM mitabla mt 
     INNER JOIN otratabla ot 
     ON mt.id = ot.id
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿para qué sirve `EXPLAIN`y cómo han de ser interpretados los resultados arrojados cuando se ejecuta la consulta de esta manera si queremos mejorar los índices de una tabla?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` te entrega el plan de ejecución de la consulta. Hay libros dedicados a entenderlos e interpretarlos , definitivamente fuera del alcance de una respuesta en SO

Comment: Todos intuímos para qué sirve. Ahora, cómo interpretarlos? Espero ver tu respuesta @acedano porque para mí es como leer las hojas del té.

Comment: @amenadiel _Espero ver tu respuesta ... porque para mí es como leer las hojas del té_ No sé si verás mi respuesta, ya tengo a los gendarmes pidiendo que la pregunta sea cerrada. Motivo: el de siempre... demasiado amplia... OMG, algunos entienden mal el concepto de amplitud. La pregunta tiene 45 minutos de existencia y ya 2 le han dado al botón para cerrar.

Comment: @Lamak _definitivamente fuera del alcance de una respuesta en SO_ ¿Por qué fuera del alcance? Estoy preguntando **dos cosas muy concretas**

Comment: @A. Cedano: La primera pregunta es concreta, pero la segunda no lo es en realidad. Realmente se necesita un libro o mas para explicar plenamente como interpretar los resultados de un EXPLAIN y saber como usar esa información para optimizar una consulta. Es en realidad un tema bien amplio.

Comment: Gracias @sstan He modificado la pregunta, porque lo que me interesa en la segunda parte de la pregunta es saber si debo mejorar los índices de la BD.

Comment: De nada. Vi la edición, pero aunque parezca sorprendente, creo que aun no es posible de dar una buena respuesta que no se extienda indefinidamente. Es posible dar una respuesta simplista que explique cuales etapas de la ejecución están usando un índice y cuales no. Y algunos dirán que para optimizar la consulta, hay que buscar cuales etapas no usan un índice y corregirlo. Pero esa explicación popular no es correcta. En realidad hay muchísimos factores a considerar, y hay veces que la forma optimal de ejecutar ciertas etapas de la ejecución es sin el uso de un índice. No es un tema sencillo.

Comment: @sstan parece complicado, pero no tanto. Me parece una excelente estrategia para optimizar nuestras consultas. En una aplicación bien organizada no es difícil obtener las diferentes posibilidades de consulta y analizarlas todas con `EXPLAIN`, sobre todo teniendo en cuenta que en este caso se trataría de ver si los índices están funcionando bien o no. Una parte de la repuesta podría abundar brevemente sobre un plan de análisis basado en `EXPLAIN`

Comment: Bueno, al menos yo no me atrevo a contestar :)  Como te digo, aunque el EXPLAIN comunique que ciertos índices no están siendo usados, no necesariamente significa que algo está mal. Sobre todo cuando tienes joins, hay veces que el motor optará por hacer un *hash join* (usualmente sin usar índice), y en otros *nested loops* (usualmente con índices), y determinar cual es la mejor manera no es tarea fácil. En mi opinión, no es algo que se pueda generalizar así no más. Pero no te miento que cuando hicistes la pregunta, pensé que la ibas a contestar y estaba curioso de ver cómo lo ibas a hacer :)

Comment: Son dos preguntas y la segunda si parece muy amplia, pero aunque no lo fuera (por su complejidad o por la extensión requerida para contestar todas las posibles opciones), es complicado cuando se hacen dos preguntas, porque si dos personas distintas contestan cada uno una pregunta diferente, ¿cuál se marca como aceptada? Hacer dos preguntas dificulta el funcionamiento del sitio, en la parte de respuestas aceptadas, no en la de creación de contenido.

Comment: @sstan Dada la mala experiencia cuando intento aportar algo (mis preguntas son condenadas a muerte casi antes de nacer) esperaré a ver si no la decapitan primero para responder. No quiero de nuevo hacer un esfuerzo y que luego la cierren haciendo clic en un botón. toledano@ entonces ¿qué sugieres, que sea sólo una pregunta, la primera parte de la misma?

Comment: Ups. Si ya tenías la respuesta, la hubieras contestado y aceptado de inmediato, sin esperar nada. La primera parte de la pregunta es clara y objetiva. La segunda pregunta es subjetiva y casuística. Me quedaría con la primera.

Comment: @toledano la tengo pero en inglés. La traduciré si la pregunta queda abierta pero si no... hacer algo para que otro le de a cerrar sin pensarlo dos veces... No.  A eso me refiero cuando digo que ese espíritu restrictivo empobrece el sitio.

Comment: Comprendo. Si no deseas compartir tus conocimientos, por las razones que sean, estás en todo tu derecho. Es tu decisión y debemos respetarla.

Comment: @toledano Creo que no entendiste lo que quise decir, no es que no quiera compartir mis conocimientos, sino que no veo el interés de compartirlos si la pregunta es cerrada. Sería un trabajo hecho en vano.

Comment: Revisa en la documentacion las explicaciones en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html y https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Gracias @Igor. Pero la doc está en inglés. Saludos.

Comment: Lamentablemente la doc. actual no aparece en español desde hace varias versiones. Para la version 5.0 aparece el tema en http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.0/es/explain.html

Comment: Recompensa iniciada para que se animen con una respuesta contundente

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tenía un artículo muy interesante guardado sobre `EXPLAIN`, que consta de 23 capítulos, con muchos ejemplos con explicación breve, para así entender mejor su funcionamiento, lástima que está en inglés y es un poco extenso, aun así, me anime a traducirlo a español de la mejor forma posible, para entenderlo mejor, ya que personalmente me parece un temario interesante.

*Código fuente:*
[Adrian Hardy's slides from PHPNW08](https://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained)
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999833/mysql-explain-query-understanding/7999996#7999996)

### 1. Explicación MySQL EXPLAIN

Rápida y Fácil Optimización de Consultas
 
*Adrián Hardy*

### 2. Antes de comenzar ...

**Lo que usted necesita saber**

- Cómo y por qué agregamos índices a tablas
- Los beneficios de mecanografía de campo correcto
- Comprensión de los ideales de `3NF`
- Comprensión básica de `SQL JOINs`

**Esta presentación**

- Introducción muy rápida a EXPLICAR
- Mejorar la comprensión de `MySQL` y la indexación
- Ejemplos / resultados simplificados

### 3. Introducción - Utilizar MySQL EXPLAIN

**Prefijo una consulta con SELECT con EXPLAIN**

- `MySQL` no ejecutará la consulta, solo la analiza
- `EXPLAIN` nos ayuda a entender cómo y cuándo `MySQL`, utilizará índices
- `EXPLAIN` devuelve una tabla de datos de la que se identifica mejoras potenciales a Optimizar
- Las consultas de tres maneras

  1. Modificar o crea índices
  2. Modificar la estructura de la consulta
  3. Modificar la estructura de datos
- Consultas optimizadas = resultados más rápidos, menor carga del servidor ...

### 4. Introducción - Revisión de la indexación

- Estructura rápida y compacta para identificar las ubicaciones de las filas
- Mantenga los índices en la memoria recortando la grasa:

  1. ¿Puedo reducir los caracteres de ese índice `VARCHAR`?
  2. ¿Puedo usar un `TINYINT` en lugar de un `BIGINT`?
  3. ¿Puedo usar un `INTEGER` para describir un estado o una bandera (más bien que una descripción textual)?
- Corte el conjunto de resultados tan pronto como sea posible
- `MySQL` sólo utilizará un índice por consulta / tabla - no puede combinar dos índices separados para hacer útil su uso*

Comprensión y preparación trae consigo la *Estrategia de Indexación*

### 5. Esquema de aplicación de reserva

*Asistentes*

```
+--------------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
| attendee_id  | surname | conference_id | registration_status | 
+--------------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
| INTEGER (PK) | VARCHAR |  INTEGER (FK) |      TINYINT        | 
+--------------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
```

*Conferencias*

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| conference_id | location_id  | topic_id     | date |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+------+
| INTEGER (PK)  | INTEGER (FK) | INTEGER (FK) | DATE |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+------+
```

### 6. EXPLAIN – Ejemplo funcionando

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123 AND registration_status > 0 

+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| tabla      |  possible_keys | key  | row   |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| asistentes |       NULL     | NULL | 14052 |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
```

Las tres columnas más importantes devueltas por `EXPLAIN`

- Posibles claves

  - Todos los posibles índices que `MySQL` podría haber utilizado
  - Basado en una serie de búsquedas y cálculos muy rápidos
- Seleccionada de Clave
- Filas escaneadas

  - Indicación del esfuerzo requerido para identificar su conjunto de resultados

### 7. EXPLAIN – Ejemplo funcionando

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123 AND registration_status > 0 

+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| tabla      |  possible_keys | key  | row   |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| asistentes |       NULL     | NULL | 14052 |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
```

*Interpretación de los resultados*

- No hay índices adecuados para esta consulta

  - `MySQL` tuvo que hacer una exploración de la tabla completa
- Escaneo de la tabla completa, su consulta es casi siempre más lenta
- Las exploraciones de tabla completa, aunque no siempre son malas, suelen ser una indicación de que se requiere un índice

### 8. EXPLAIN – Ejemplo funcionando

```
ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX conf (id_conferencia); 

ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX reg (registration_status); 

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123 AND registration_status > 1 

+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| tabla      |  possible_keys | key  | row   |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| asistentes |    conf,reg    | conf | 331   |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
```

- `MySQ`L tiene dos índices para elegir, pero descartado *"reg"*
- *"reg"* no es lo suficientemente único

  - La propagación de valores también puede ser un factor (por ejemplo, cuando el 99% de filas Contienen el mismo valor)
- Índice *"unicidad"* se llama cardinalidad
- Hay margen para algún aumento de rendimiento ...

  - Menor carga del servidor, una respuesta más rápida

### 9. EXPLAIN – Ejemplo funcionando

```
ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX reg_conf_index (registration_status, conference_id);

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123 AND registration_status > 1 

+------------+-----------------+----------------+-------+
| tabla      |  possible_keys  | key            | row   |
+------------+-----------------+----------------+-------+
| asistentes |    reg, conf,   | reg_conf_index | 204   |
|            | reg_conf_index  |                |       |
+------------+-----------------+----------------+-------+
```

- **reg_conf_index** es una opción mucho mejor
- Tenga en cuenta que las otras dos claves están todavía disponibles, sólo no es tan efectivo
- Nuestra consulta es bien servida por el nuevo índice

### 10. EXPLAIN – Ejemplo funcionando

```
DELETE INDEX conf; DELETE INDEX reg; 

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123

+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| tabla      |  possible_keys | key  | row   |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| asistentes |       NULL     | NULL | 14052 |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
```

- Sin el índice *"conf"*, volvemos al cuadrado uno
- El orden en el cual los campos fueron definidos en un índice compuesto afecta si está disponible para utilizar en una consulta

  - Recuerde que definimos nuestro índice: (`registration_status`, `conference_id`)

*Solución potencial:*

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123 AND registration_status> = -1 

+------------+----------------+----------------+-----+
| tabla      |  possible_keys | key            | row |
+------------+----------------+----------------+-----+
| asistentes | reg_conf_index | reg_conf_index | 204 |
+------------+----------------+----------------+-----+
```

### 11. EXPLAIN - Ejemplo 2

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE surname LIKE 'har%'; 

+------------+----------------+---------+-----+
| tabla      |  possible_keys | key     | row |
+------------+----------------+---------+-----+
| asistentes |     surname    | surname | 234 |
+------------+----------------+---------+-----+
```

***MySQL*** utiliza un índice de surname (apellido) - que es bueno.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE surname LIKE '% har%'; 

+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| tabla      |  possible_keys | key  | row   |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| asistentes |       NULL     | NULL | 14052 |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
```

***¡MySQL*** ni siquiera intenta usar un índice!

### 12. EXPLAIN - Ejemplo 3

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM conferencias WHERE location_id = 2 OR topic_id IN (4,6,1)

+--------------+----------------+------+------+
| tabla        |  possible_keys | key  | row  |
+--------------+----------------+------+------+
| conferencias |  location_id,  | NULL | 5043 |
|              |   topic_id     |      |      |
+--------------+----------------+------+------+
```

***MySQL*** no utiliza un índice, debido a la **OR**

```
ALTER TABLA ADD INDEX location_topic (location_id, topic_id);

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM conferencias WHERE location_id = 2 OR topic_id IN (4,6,1)

+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----+
| tabla        |  possible_keys | key            | row |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----+
| conferencias |  location_id,  | location_topic | 15  |
|              |   topic_id,    |                |     |
|              | location_topic |                |     |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----+
```

*Escaneo completo de tablas evitado - también podría utilizar el truco de **UNION (ALL)***

### 13. EXPLAIN - Ejemplo 4

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE MD5 (conference_id) = MD5 (123)

+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| tabla      |  possible_keys | key  | row   |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
| asistentes |       NULL     | NULL | 14052 |
+------------+----------------+------+-------+
```

*Comprensiblemente, `MySQL` tiene que hacer una exploración completa de la tabla*

**¿Un ejemplo más realista?**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM conferencias WHERE DATE_FORMAT (date, '%a') = 'Sat' 

+--------------+----------------+------+------+
| tabla        |  possible_keys | key  | row  |
+--------------+----------------+------+------+
| conferencias |      NULL      | NULL | 5043 |
+--------------+----------------+------+------+
```

*Un buen candidato para la optimización # 3 - Modificar la estructura de datos*

### 14. JOINs

- Unir grandes conjuntos de datos (`> = 100.000`) es realmente donde
  `EXPLAIN` es útil
- Cada `JOIN` en una consulta obtiene su propia fila en `EXPLAIN`

  - Asegúrese de que cada condición `JOIN` sea ‘rápido’
- Asegúrese de que cada tabla unida está llegando a su conjunto de resultados tan pronto como sea posible

  - Los beneficios se combinan si cada unión requiere menos esfuerzo

### 15. JOINs - Ejemplo simple

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM 
conferencias INNER JOIN asistentes USING (conference_id) 
WHERE conferences.location_id = 2 AND 
conferencias.topic_id IN (4,6,1) AND 
participantes.registration_status > 1 

+--------------+------+------------------+------------------+-------+
| tabla        | type | possible_keys    |        key       | row   |
+--------------+------+------------------+------------------+-------+ 
| conferencias | ref  | conference_topic | conference_topic | 15    | 
+--------------+------+------------------+------------------+-------+
| asistentes   | ALL  |       NULL       |       NULL       | 14052 |
+--------------+------+------------------+------------------+-------+
```

Parece que necesito un *índice* en *asistentes.conference_id*

Hay **13** valores diferentes para "**type**"

- Otra indicación de esfuerzo, aparte de las filas escaneadas
- Aquí, `ALL` es malo - debemos ser apuntando a `ref`
- Los valores comunes son `const`, `ref` y `todos`
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/using-explain.html

### 16. La columna "extra"

Con cada `EXPLAIN`, se obtiene una columna *"extra"*, que muestra las operaciones adicionales invocadas para obtener el conjunto de resultados.

```
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+----------------+
|tabla      | possible_keys | key  | row | extra          |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+----------------+
|asistentes | conf          | conf | 331 |  Using where,  |
|           |               |      |     | Using filesort |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+----------------+
```

Algunos ejemplos de valores *"extra"*:

- Uso de where
- Uso de tabla temporal
- Uso de archivo
- Uso de índice

Existen muchos más valores *"extra"* que se tratan en el manual de `MySQL`.

### 17. "Usando filesort"

*Evite, porque:*

- No utiliza un índice

  - Implica una exploración completa de su conjunto de resultados
  - Emplea un algoritmo genérico (es decir, un tamaño para todos)
  - Utiliza el sistema de archivos (eeek)
  - Obtendrá Más lenta con más datos

*No todo es malo ...*

- Perfectamente aceptable siempre que llegues a tu conjunto de
  resultados lo más rápido posible, y manténgalo predeciblemente
  pequeño
- A veces inevitable - `ORDER BY RAND ()`
- Las operaciones `ORDER BY` pueden usar índices para hacer ¡clasificación!

### 18. "Usando filesort" – Ejemplo

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123 ORDER BY surname

+------------+---------------+---------------+-----+----------------+
| tabla      | possible_keys | key           | row | extra          |
+------------+---------------+---------------+-----+----------------+
| asistentes | conference_id | conference_id | 331 | Using filesort |
+------------+---------------+---------------+-----+----------------+
```

***MySQL*** utiliza un índice, pero está ordenando los resultados lentamente

```
ALTER TABLE asistentes ADD INDEX Conf_surname (conference_id, surname);

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123 ORDER BY surname

+------------+----------------+--------------+-----+-------+
| tabla      | possible_keys  | key          | row | extra |
+------------+----------------+--------------+-----+-------+
| asistentes | conference_id, | conf_surname | 331 |       |
|            | conf_surname   |              |     |       |                                         
+------------+----------------+--------------+-----+-------+
```

*Hemos evitado un **filesort** (archivo de archivos)*

### 19. "Utilizando el índice (INDEX)"

Celebre, porque:

- `MySQL` obtuvo sus resultados sólo consultando el índice,

  - Que bien podría haber estado sentado en la memoria
- `MySQL` no necesita ni siquiera mirar a la mesa para obtener sus resultados

  - Abrir una mesa puede ser una operación costosa.
- `MySQL` puede responder a la siguiente consulta más rápidamente

  - ¿La forma más rápida de obtener sus datos?

Particularmente útil ...

- Cuando sólo está interesado en una sola `fecha` o un `ID`
- El `COUNT ()`, `SUM ()`, `AVG ()` etc. de un campo

### 20. "Usar el índice (INDEX)" – Ejemplo

```
EXPLAIN SELECT AVG (age) FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123

+------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-------+
| tabla      | possible_keys | key           | row | extra |
+------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-------+
| asistentes | conference_id | conference_id | 331 |       |
+------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-------+
```

*¡Nada es realmente incorrecto con esta consulta - podría ser más rápido!*

```
ALTER TABLE asistentes ADD INDEX conf_age (conference_id, age);

EXPLAIN SELECT AVG (age) FROM asistentes WHERE conference_id = 123

+------------+----------------+--------------+-----+-------------+
| tabla      | possible_keys  | key          | row | extra       |
+------------+----------------+--------------+-----+-------------+
| asistentes | conference_id, | conf_surname | 331 | Using index |
|            | conf_surname   |              |     |             |                                         
+------------+----------------+--------------+-----+-------------+
```

*Fuera del almacenamiento en caché, la manera más rápida de obtener sus datos (No es una garantía)*

### 21. Avanzando ...

Simplemente porque tus consultas son rápidas ahora, no significa que se mantendrán de esa manera para siempre

Habilitar el registro de consultas lentas de `MySQL`

- --log-slow-queries = / var / lib / mysql / slow -query.log
- Predeterminado a las consultas de registro que tardan más de 10 segundos
- --long_query_time = 1
- Utilizar el parche de "microslow" de Percona para los valores <1 segundo
- Buscar la consulta en el registro, EXPLAIN, mejórela, enjuague y repita

### 22. Avanzando ...

Utilice la línea de comandos para identificar problemas más generales

- mysqladmin -u dbuser -p -r -i 10 extended-status
- Las figuras son relativas, actualizadas cada 10 segundos

  - Slow_queries = número de consultas lentas en Último período
  - Select_Scan = exploraciones de tabla completa
  - Select_full_join = exploraciones completas para completar operaciones de unión
  - Created_tmp_disk_tables = filesorts
  - Key_read_requests / Key_write_requests

    - Determinar la ponderación de escritura / lectura de nuestra aplicación y modificar sus índices en consecuencia

Answer (score 3):

La instrucción EXPLAIN proporciona información sobre cómo MySQL ejecuta las sentencias o consultas:

`EXPLAIN` funciona con las instrucciones `SELECT`, `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `REPLACE` y `UPDATE`.

Como `EXPLICA` el [Manual de Referencia de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html):

> Cuando se utiliza `EXPLAIN` MySQL muestra información del optimizador sobre el plan de ejecución de la sentencia. Es decir, MySQL explica (EXPLAIN) cómo procesaría la sentencia, **incluyendo información sobre cómo se unen las tablas y en qué orden**.

En lenguaje coloquial, cuando usamos `EXPLAIN` le decimos a MySQL: *explícame cómo procesas tú esta sentencia*.

### Utilidad de EXPLAIN

Con la ayuda de EXPLAIN,

- Es posible ver dónde se debe agregar índices a tablas para que la sentencia se ejecute más rápido mediante el uso de índices para buscar filas.
- También se puede utilizar EXPLAIN para comprobar si el optimizador une a las tablas (JOIN) en un orden óptimo. Para dar una sugerencia al optimizador de que utilice un orden de combinación correspondiente al orden en que se nombran las tablas en una sentencia SELECT, se debe comenzar la sentencia con SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN en lugar de SELECT.

La traza del optimizador a veces puede proporcionar información complementaria a la de EXPLAIN. Sin embargo, el formato de rastreo del optimizador y el contenido están sujetos a cambios entre versiones.

Si tiene un problema con los índices que no se utilizan cuando cree que deberían hacerlo, ejecute ANALYZE TABLE para actualizar estadísticas de tabla, como la cardinalidad de las claves, que pueden afectar las opciones que el optimizador realiza.

### Ejecuntando EXPLAIN

Cuando se ejecuta EXPLAIN MySQL nos devuelve una tabla con varias filas, en concreto la información de cada fila  corresponde a las distintas tablas que intervienen en la consulta.

#### Opción `FORMAT`

Cuando ejecutamos `EXPLAIN` podemos indicar a través de la opción `FORMAT` el formato de salida: `TRADITIONAL` presenta la salida en formato tabular. Este es el valor predeterminado si no hay ninguna opción FORMAT. El formato `JSON` muestra la información en formato JSON.

Para ver la sintaxis completa de `EXPLAIN` se puede consultar el [Manual de Referencia de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html).

### Ejemplo de una consulta y su resultado

Dada la siguiente tabla, con valores:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `age` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
  `sex` enum('MALE','FEMALE') default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `age_sex` (`age`,`sex`),
  KEY `sex_age` (`sex`,`age`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM user WHERE age=42 AND sex="MALE";

+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user  | ref  | age_sex,sex_age | age_sex | 4       | const,const |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### ¿Qué significan las columnas que vemos en los resultados?

- Table: Nos informa de la tabla a la que nos estamos refiriendo.
- **Type**: El tipo de unión que se está usando. **Es una columna muy importante para el análisis.** A continuación detallamos el significado de cada uno, empezando por el mejor hasta el peor.

  - System: Tabla con una única fila, por tanto, la respuesta es inmediata.
  - Const: En la tabla coincide una única fila con los criterios indicados. Al sólo haber una fila, el optimizador toma este valor como constante, por este motivo este tipo de tablas son muy rápidas.
  - Eq_ref: Una fila de la tabla 1 será leída por cada combinación de filas de la tabla 2. Este tipo es usado cuando todas las partes de un índice se usan en la consulta y el índice es UNIQUE o PRIMARY KEY.
  - Ref: Todas las filas con valores en el índice que coincidan serán leídos desde esta tabla por cada combinación de filas de las tablas previas. Similar a eq_ref, pero usado cuando usa sólo un prefijo más a la izquierda de la clave o si la clave no es UNIQUE o PRIMARY KEY. Si la clave que es usada coincide sólo con pocas filas, esta union es buena.
  - Range: Sólo serán recuperadas las filas que estén en un rango dado, usando un índice para seleccionar las filas. La columna key indica cual índice es usado, y el valor key_len contiene la parte más grande de la clave que fue usada. La columna ref será NULL para este tipo.
  - Index: Escaneo completo de la tabla para cada combinación de filas de las tablas previas, revisando únicamente el índice.
  - ALL: Escaneo completo de la tabla para cada combinación de filas. Es el peor caso ya que revisará todas las filas para cada combinación.
- Possible_keys: Posibles indices que utilizará la consulta.
- Key: Índice utilizado para ejecutar la consulta. Si indica el valor NULL, no se ha escogido ningún índice.
- Key_len: Cuanto más pequeño sea este valor, más rápida será la
  consulta, pues nos indica la longitud del índice usado.
- Ref: Las columnas del índice que se está usando, o una constante si
  esta es posible.
- Rows: Número de filas que MySQL debe analizar para devolver los datos
  solicitados.
- Extra: Información complementaria sobre como MySQL ejecutará la
  consulta. Los posibles valores en este campo pueden ser:
- Distinct: MySQL ha encontrado una fila coincidente con los filtros
  indicados y no necesita seguir analizando.
- Not exists: MySQL fue capaz de hacer una optimización LEFT JOIN sobre
  la consulta y no examinará más filas en la tabla para la combinación
  de filas previa después de que encuentre una fila que coincida con el
  criterio LEFT JOIN.
- Range checked for each record: No se encontró un índice válido. Para
  cada combinación de filas se hará un chequeo para determinar que
  indice utilizar y en caso de encontrar alguno válido, lo utilizará.
- Using filesort: Este valor indica que MySQL necesita hacer un paso
  extra para encontrar la forma de ordenar las filas. Este tipo de
  consultas debe ser optimizada.
- Using index: Recupera la información solicitada utilizando únicamente
  la información del índice. Esto sucede cuando todas las columnas
  requeridas forman parte del índice.
- Using temporary: Para resolver esta consulta, MySQL creará una tabla
  temporal. Uno de los casos típicos en los que devuelve este valor es
  cuando usamos un ORDER BY sobre un conjunto de columnas diferentes a
  las indicadas en la clausula GROUP BY. Este tipo de consultas debe
  ser optimizada.
- Where used: Se usará una clausula WHERE para determinar que filas
  serán comparadas con otra tabla. Si no deseamos regresar todas las
  filas desde la tabla, y el join es del tipo ALL o index, es muy
  probable que hayamos escrito algo mal en la consulta.

Conociendo el significado de cada columna devuelta por `EXPLAIN`podemos analizar con más claridad la forma en que MySQL está ejecutando nuestras consultas y podremos ver si algún índice no está funcionando o si necesita ser añadido o mejorado.

Comment: Hola hermano. Admiro tu esfuerzo, dedicación y coraje al afrontar un tema tan complicado. Pero en mi humilde opinión, la respuesta confirma cuan amplia es la (2da parte de la) pregunta. Porque a pesar de la (larga) explicación, no creo que abarca lo que yo pensaba era el objetivo principal de la (2da parte de la) pregunta: ¿cómo usar la información para optimizar una consulta cualquiera?  Aunque sí veo que en algunos lugares especificas *Este tipo de consultas debe ser optimizada*, no especifica cómo hacerlo, ni tampoco estoy convencido que se pueda generalizar que la consulta requiera mejora.

Comment: Tal vez hubiera sido mejor limitar la(s) pregunta(s) a simplemente: 1) ¿para qué sirve `EXPLAIN`? y 2) ¿qué significan los resultados del `EXPLAIN`?  Pero la parte de cómo *interpretar* o *traducir* los resultados de forma a determinar si la consulta necesita mejoras y cuáles mejoras necesita, eso sigo pensando que es demasiado amplio para el formato pregunta y respuesta.

Comment: @sstan Tienes razón. Aunque como dice la respuesta: _Es posible ver dónde se debe **agregar índices a tablas para que la sentencia se ejecute más rápido** mediante el uso de índices para buscar filas... También se puede utilizar EXPLAIN para comprobar si el optimizador une a las tablas (JOIN) en un orden óptimo_ Yo me refería a eso, a que `EXPLAIN` nos ofrece detalles interesantes, leyendo sobre todo la columna **Type**, la cual he puesto en negritas. Si en dicha columna tenemos **ref** no es lo mismo que si tuviésemos **ALL**, en ese sentido `EXPLAIN` sirve también como optimizador.

Comment: Aun así, te confieso que algunas afirmaciones me incomodan un poco porque creo que están insinuando y generalizando cosas que no son ciertas (me corriges si estoy malinterpretando). Por ejemplo: *Es posible ver dónde se debe agregar índices a tablas para que la sentencia se ejecute más rápido*. 1) Insinúa que el uso de índices siempre resulta en una mejora de rendimiento, pero esto no es cierto.  2) insinúa que si en cierta etapa de la ejecución no se está usando un índice, es porque falta un índice, lo que tampoco es cierto. Tal vez el índice existe, pero simplemente no es óptimo usarlo.

Comment: @sstan Esa parte la he tomado del Manual de referencia de MuSQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html no me la he inventado yo. Yo uso EXPLAIN para depurar consultas complicadas y siempre me indica algún que otro índice mal colocado que cambia la eficacia de los resultados.

Answer (score 1):

La sentencia EXPLAIN devuelve una tabla con una serie de filas con información sobre cada una de las tablas empleadas en la consulta a la que acompaña. EXPLAIN se puede emplear en las siguientes consultas: SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE y UPDATE. Para emplear esta sentencia, bastará con poner EXPLAIN seguido de la consulta que queremos analizar. Por ejemplo:
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mi_tabla;

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users;
```

que devuelve:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
```

La tabla que devuelve la sentencia EXPLAIN lista las tablas en el orden en el que MySQL las leería procesando la consulta (la primera fila que aparece sería la primera tabla que se lee y la última fila sería la última tabla que sería leída). Este orden es importante conocerlo ya que nos indicará el plan de ejecución de la consulta y, por tanto, información relevante para realizar nuestras optimizaciones.

Para mas información puedes visitar https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html