# Corrupcion de base de datos montada en servidor

Tags: mysql

Estoy recibiendo un curso de programación avanzada en PHP en una miniempresa que tiene dos servidores:

- PRINCIPAL: contienen los programas principales
- DESARROLLO: aquí se van mejorando los sistemas y luego se suben al principal

Hay cinco computadores y cinco personas que trabajan y aparte el administrador del phpmyadmin y en su caso de los servidores, el controla todo el acceso de phpmyadmin de los usuarios que hay, a la base de datos principal.

Ocurre lo siguiente, hay un sistema que estaba guardando los registros de usuarios y muchos datos de ellos, iban alrededor de 80000 registros, el sistema fue actualizado hace como 1 mes y siguió funcionando bien, hace 3 días, la tabla empezó a dar problemas, cuando querías ir al último registro te sacaba del PHPmyAdmin, aquí se pensaba que eran privilegios, pero todos tenían acceso total, incluso por PHPmyAdmin podías insertar datos pero no verlos, el sistema empezó a arrojar errores de MySQL, numero 2013

Estuve leyendo y eso ocurre

- porque se agota el tiempo de respuesta
- problemas de acceso o firewall.

Todas las pc tienen acceso, el firewall esta desactivado, el tiempo de espera se cambió a uno mayor.

Hay otro sistema que hace consultas de incluso 60 campos, este sistema solo tiene 17.

La otra tabla se cierra sola más o menos en la mitad o un cuarto de los registros, es decir llega al 30000 y se sale.

Al parecer se corrompió la base de datos, pero solo el administrador que les dije tiene acceso, ¿pudo haber hecho algo él?, o de qué manera se pudo haber corrompido dicha base de datos.

Lo digo porque también la tenía tiempo haciendo pruebas de SQL INYECTION a ese sistema, porque la actualización descubrió algunas fallitas, también se veía interés de su parte de demostrar que el creador de ese sistema no tenía capacidad y conocimientos suficientes.

Cabe destacar que el día que nos dimos cuenta que el sistema fallaba, ese mismo día le hicieron un respaldo a todos los sistemas el cual no estaba programado

•   Quisiera saber cómo se podría reparar la tabla

•   Es posible acceder a la carpeta Xamp, mysql y copiarlo todo

•   Como conocer si fue un ataque SQL

Se que la pregunta puede entrar en opiniones, pero me gustaría conocer un proceso que mas o menos podría aplicar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y es difícil dar una respuesta definitiva ante un problema tan complejo.

Como dices, quizá la BD se haya corrompido, quizá recibió un ataque de Inyección SQL, quizá la BD está mal diseñada (índices mal colocados, datos redundantes, etc), esto último es muy frecuente, o sea, un diseño mal concebido funciona bien pero cuando los datos empiezan a crecer tienes errores del tipo 2013... porque hay muchos datos y no se están gestionando de la mejor manera. O simplemente ¡es un problema del PhpMyAdmin y no de los datos!

Antes que nada, haz una copia actual de tus datos y no tires a la papelera las copias anteriores.

Luego empieza a analizar la BD, empezando quizá por lo último que te he dicho.

Para depurar que no sea simplemente problema de la interfaz, algún error del PHPMyAdmin, con crear un archivo php de prueba que haga cualquiera de esas consultas que te están dando problemas y verificando si se ejecutan satisfactoriamente o no estarás evaluando un posible problema que no tiene en realidad nada que ver con tus datos. O sea, evalúa primero si el problema actual no viene de algo que es externo a tus datos.

Luego si verificas que todo lo que es externo funciona bien, pasa a analizar tus datos. *La ley empieza por casa*, dicen. Entonces, antes de pensar en un hacker, piensa en un posible mal diseño de la BD que funcionó bien durante un tiempo, pero que ahora no lo hace porque la misma es grande y ya debe hacer manejos que resultan penosos a causa de un mal diseño.

Por ejemplo:

¿Qué ocurre si haces una de esas consultas en las que la BD da error 2013 poniendo delante `EXPLAIN` ? Imagínate que esa consulta está mal escrita, o que los índices están mal y el sistema en vez de una fila está leyendo 80,000

En ese sentido, `EXPLAIN`podría ser interesante para tu caso. Te dejo [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55385/29967), por si quieres explorar esa posibilidad.

Si el diseño está optimizado, normalizado y las consultas bien escritas, entonces tendrías que empezar a explorar otras causas, yendo siempre de lo más particular a lo general. O sea, el problema a veces está de parte nuestra que somos los que manipulamos a las máquinas. ¿Cómo hemos diseñado, almacenado, consultado esos datos? A veces no lo hacemos de la mejor manera y por eso el sistema se queja. ¿Cómo los hemos asegurado para que no haya ataques? ... Es necesario hacerse muchas preguntas e irlas respondiendo con análisis concretos hasta dar con la causa.

Comment: Te agrego lo siguiente, el disco duro donde esta la base de datos le quedaban unos pocos gygas (5 creo), segundo lugar, consultando, insertando, buscando, eliminando, modificando, te sale el mismo error, si lo haces por el sistema, si lo haces directo en phpmyadmin te saca del php, es decir, vuelves a la pantalla inicial y se te borra la clave.

Otra cosa es que en donde esta el servidor ha habido mucho calor.

Otra cosa adicional, es que ese mismo dia, tambien se modifico otro sistema que jala los datos del que te hablo, es decir.

El sistema dñado le daba datos a otros sistemas

Comment: Uff, las causas pueden ser múltiples. Todo eso del disco duro entra en un primer grupo de cosas a evaluar. Lo más importante son los datos, no se pueden tener almacenados en medios con poca capacidad. Otra causa de primer grado sería un ordenador lento, desactualizado... causas pueden haber miles y con un problema añadido, si no eres el que administra los datos, si no tienes acceso a todo es imposible evaluar, debe hacerlo todo el equipo encargado de la BD.

Comment: el encargado decidio esperar que llegara el 2do al mando que esta de vacaciones para revisar, lo que consiguieron fue un respaldo de hace 1 mes, la cosa por la que diria que fue hackeo, es porque el actual administrador dice que no puede respaldar nada, porque la tabla que se corrompio "daño" todos los sistemas, y nadie le cree eso.

En fin jejeje, pregunte porque me parecio algo interesante, ver el comportamiento de los sistemas, ante fallas, ante problemas tecnicos y demas

Comment: @VictorA. Respaldo de hace 1 mes, ¡imagínate!, si es una BD en la que agregas/modificas registros cada 29 días un sistema de respaldo mensual está bien, pero si la BD es actualizada con más frecuencia, independientemente de hackeo, el error es nuestro al no haber implementado backups más frecuentes. El _que deja entrar al hacker y deja que el hacker dañe datos de forma irreversible es un hacker al cuadrado_ :) No se trata de culpabilizar a nadie, sino de que cuando manejamos un sistema somos responsables de él, de su seguridad y de que, si hay hackeo (que puede haber), los daños sean menores.