# Existencia del Missing Index en MySQL ¿Existe?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

He estado trabajando un poco con MySQL y SQL Server, y me encuentro con una duda: `si el script "Missing Index" existe en MySQL`

En SQL Server sé que muestra los indices faltantes de cada tabla en una base de datos, y por tal quisiera saber si existe en MySQL o algo parecido a este script de SQl Server que se pueda ejecutar.

De ante mano se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Imagino que el objetivo sería determinar si las tablas de la BD tienen los **índices creados adecuadamente **, ya que un índice tiene una razón de ser. La forma de determinar si los índices se usan adecuadamente en MySQL es mediante EXPLAIN. [Aquí tienes respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53779/mysql-para-qu%C3%A9-sirve-explain-en-una-consulta-y-c%C3%B3mo-interpretar-los-resultados) que te explican cómo.

Comment: Ya intente con el comando EXPLAIN pero lo que en realidad quiero saber es a que tablas les falta indices y a cuales no pero en MySQL

Comment: Entonces creo que el título de la pregunta debe cambiar. A mi esta consulta me muestra todas las tablas que no tienen índices creados: `select 
    t.table_schema, t.table_name 
from 
    information_schema.tables  t 
    left join information_schema.statistics s 
       on t.table_schema=s.table_schema and t.table_name=s.table_name 
       and s.non_unique=0 
where 
    s.table_name is null and t.table_schema='NOMBRE-BASE-DE-DATOS';` debes sustituir lo último por el nombre de la BD. Lo he probado y me funciona.

Comment: Si amigo si me funciono :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar las tablas de la base de datos que no tengan ningún índice, podrías hacerlo mediante esta consulta:

```
select 
    t.table_schema, t.table_name 
from 
    information_schema.tables t 
    inner join information_schema.columns c  
        on t.table_schema=c.table_schema and t.table_name=c.table_name 
where 
     t.table_schema='AQUÍ-NOMBRE-DE-TU-BASE-DE-DATOS'
group by 
    t.table_schema,t.table_name   
having 
    sum(if(column_key in ('PRI','UNI'), 1,0)) =0
;
```

En el `where t.table_schema=` debes indicar el nombre de tu base de datos.

Lo he probado y me funciona.

**Nota:** Esta funciona más rápido que la del comentario.

Comment: Si amigo los dos funcionaron bien y si me dio el resultado que esperaba :)

Comment: @SantiagoHuh me alegro. Puedes también dar un voto a favor a la respuesta usando la flecha gris de la izquierda que apunta hacia arriba.

Comment: Si ya lo hice, solo que me dice que se guardara pero no se mostrara porque solo se puede de reputacion de 15 en adelante pero gracias por el consejo ;)

Comment: Ya pude dar tu punto a favor :)

Comment: Gracias. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.

Comment: :) A ti por el tiempo prestado

Answer (score 1):

Si me funciono los dos codigo enviados por @A.Cedano y lo modifique un poquito quedandome asi:

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, 
    IFNULL(kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 'Not indexed') AS `Index` 
 FROM information_schema.TABLES t 
     INNER JOIN information_schema.`COLUMNS` c 
    ON c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME 
    AND c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Id' 
LEFT JOIN information_schema.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` kcu 
    ON kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME 
    AND kcu.COLUMN_NAME = c.COLUMN_NAME 
    AND kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION = 1    
WHERE kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA IS NULL 
    AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql');
```

Comment: @A. Cedano si, me sirvio sus dos codigos.