# Consulta lenta PHP MySQL

Tags: php, sql

tengo un problema de lentitud al hacer una consulta a la bd, es de la web de un amigo y no tengo mucha idea de php pero el apartado que hace la consulta es el siguiente código.

```
function get($id_usuario=false){
        global $wpdb;

        if($id_usuario){                
            $tabla = $wpdb->prefix."mod_usuarios";
            $consulta = "Select * from $tabla where id_usuario='$id_usuario' ";

            $resultado =  $wpdb->get_results($consulta);
            foreach($resultado as $fila){
                $clCliente = new acClientes();
                $clCliente->formateaSalida($fila);

            }
            return $clCliente;  
        }
        else{
            $tabla = $wpdb->prefix."mod_usuarios";
            $consulta = "Select * from $tabla ";

            $resultados = $wpdb->get_results($consulta);            
            $array = array();
            $i=0;
            foreach($resultados as $fila){
                $array[$i] = new acClientes();
                $array[$i]->formateaSalida($fila);
                $i++;
            }
            return $array;                  
        }
```

Hay unos 900 registros (y 6 campos) y cuando hago la consulta en la bd usando el  `Select * from wp_mod_usuarios` tarda menos de medio segundo. Pero si lo hago así con el código de arriba tarda más de 20 segundos.

No sé dónde está el problema, he estado leyendo que con el php no es lo mismo que hacerlo a través de phpmyadmin pero tanta diferencia?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: no deberia haber semejante diferencia.. pero estas seguro que es el query, o el post procesamiento de la pagina de resultado???

Comment: Voy a hacer una suposición, para _phpMyAdmin_ 900 registros los muestra con bastante facilidad. Pero si le das salida a esos 900 registros en el navegador, lo más probable es que se demore un poco, el tiempo ya depende de ciertos factores. ¿Has probado a limitar la consulta? Tipo `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 20`

Comment: Limitala y crea una paginacion, la velocidad depende de varios factores en primer lugar la capacidad de procesamiento de tu pc y/o hosting y en segundo lugar en caso de estar usando hosting la velocidad de tu internet

Comment: @gbianchi la verdad es que no lo sé, cómo puedo comprobarlo?


 Perdón, se me olvidó comentar antes, usando el limit si me los muestra rápidamente si limito a grupos pequeños.
Pensé en hacer paginación pero no sé como hacerlo exactamente.
Y realmente tarda lo mismo en local que en el hosting donde está ahora mismo.

Comment: En los bucles estás definiendo tantos objetos como resultados de la consulta, pero solo los usas para ejecutar el método formateasalida. Que hace ese método?  Imprime en la pantalla?  Si esto es así sería más rápido crear un único objeto antes del id y usarlo.  De todas formas no queda muy claro el uso del código,  ya que la consulta es la misma,  no usas la variable tabla, en el else devuelves 900 objetos acclientes vacíos...

Comment: @AngelCid Buenas, estoy revisando el código y estaba mal, estuve editando haciendo pruebas y modifiqué eso sin saber. Lo acabo de corregir en la consulta si usa el $tabla.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hay varios factores por los que un **código** puede ir lento.

Fíjate que he dicho **código** y no he dicho *consulta*, porque en ocasiones el problema puede no ser la consulta.

No obstante, tu instrucción SQL no está **optimizada**.

1. Entonces lo primero en este caso sería optimizar tu consulta SQL. Para ello hay un primerísimo paso que es el siguiente: No uses **nunca** `SELECT *`, a no ser que vayas a utilizar **todos los campos o columnas de la tabla**. Imaginemos una tabla con 20, 40, 50, 100 columnas de las cuales en una consulta determinada sólo vas a necesitar el `id, nombre, apellidos ...`, si haces un `SELECT *`, lo cual veo desgraciadamente con mucha frecuencia... si tu tabla tiene 50 columnas y sólo necesitas 3, estarías seleccionando inútilmente 47 columnas con las cuales no vas a operar en ese momento. Entonces: **1ª regla de optimización, no, no y no a `SELECT *`**
2. **Que los índices de las tablas sean los adecuados** Una tabla mal indexada, aunque tenga 900 registros, puede empezar a ser **leeenta** y terminará siendo realmente **deseperante** en la medida en que vaya creciendo. Para determinar si los índices de la tabla están bien establecidos puedes usar `EXPLAIN SELECT columna1, column3, solocolumnaquenecesites FROM tabla WHERE ...` Al principio parece complicado, pero a través de `EXPLAIN` verás rápidamente de qué forma están funcionando los índices de la tabla. Valdría la pena dedicarle un poco de tiempo. [En esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53779/29967) podrás entender el funcionamiento de `EXPLAIN` con claridad. Es un excelente aliado para optimizar nuestras tablas. Aquí cuando hablo de **índices** me refiero no solamente a las claves primarias y foráneas, sino también a los índices de unicidad. Por ejemplo cuando un índice está mal `EXPLAIN` te dirá que tu consulta en vez de leer 1, 2, 5... filas está leyendo 900 ó 10,000 ó varios millones de filas, sobre todo cuando unes varias tablas mediante `JOIN` en tu instrucción SQL. (No es el caso aquí, pero creo conveniente señalarlo).
3. ¿Wordpress o PDO-MySQLi para manejar la base de datos? Yo en particular usaría PDO, y trataría mis datos mediante consultas preparadas, pare **evitar la [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)**, se trata de un tema algo amplio pero que hay que conocer de cara a la seguridad de nuestros datos. No te lo podría decir con propiedad, pero estoy casi seguro que Wordpress sería más lento manejando nuestra base de datos que usar el drive mismo de PDO. (Sería un tema de pregunta interesante aquí en SO).
4. La otra parte del código que no tiene que ver con la consulta a la BD. Puede ser que el problema de optimización se encuentre del lado del código que maneja los datos ya obtenidos, en este caso las funciones:

   ```
           $clCliente = new acClientes();
           $clCliente->formateaSalida($fila);
   ```

O también aquí:

```
        $array = array();
        $i=0;
        foreach($resultados as $fila){
            $array[$i] = new acClientes();
            $array[$i]->formateaSalida($fila);
            $i++;
        }
        return $array;
```

Resulta que PDO tiene métodos para devolvernos en una array (o en muchas otras formas) nuestro conjunto de resultados. Y es otro error que veo con frecuencia en código de SO, me refiero a que veo código que *reinventa la rueda*, tratando de hacer, a veces con poco éxito, algo que ya el driver de manejo de la base de datos hace a través de sus propios métodos.

**P. D.:**

Si te decides por PDO [aquí tienes una clase ya hecha](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO) (aunque tengo pendiente mejorarla) que te serviría para las funciones básicas de consulta y manejo de datos de forma segura.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Aunque la *clase ya hecha* es reinvención de la rueda. Ten cuidado cuando criticas sobre ello. PDO tiene en su clase suficiente manejo y accesibilidad como para pensar en crear una clase que controle lo mismo que hace PDO ¬¬

Comment: @MáximaAlekz difiero de esto: _la clase ya hecha es reinvención de la rueda_ ya que no es así. No sé si sabes por ejemplo que  PDO (que no es una clase) tiene sus **fallos**. Por ejemplo, si no está bien configurada con respecto a las excepciones te puedes encontrar con que en el error_log está revelando las credenciales de conexión (es algo incomprensible, pero ocurre si no te conectas con los buenos parámetros) ... **uno de los fines principales de la clase es precisamente ese**, además, si no apagas las consultas emuladas, te pueden colar una inyección, etc. Y otras muchas **ventajas**.

Comment: Por otra parte, si te fijas en el enlace de Github que pongo en la respuesta podrás apreciar la sencillez con que se pueden enviar consultas preparadas a la clase y la facilidad para obtener los datos. Pero hay otro motivo y **ese sólo me bastaría para tener mi propia clase**: me refiero a la seguridad de la contraseña de mi base de datos. Como puedes ver en la clase se encuentra en un archivo fuera del root el cual es leído únicamente desde la clase de conexión. Muy útil si quieres que dichos datos permanezcan alejados de otros usuarios con acceso a public_html.

Answer (score 1):

No se donde pueda estar el problema, pero te añadí un par de mejoras:

```
function get( $id_usuario=false ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $x = new acClientes();

        if ( $id_usuario ){                
            $tabla = $wpdb->prefix . "mod_usuarios";
            $consulta = "Select * from {$tabla} where id_usuario = '{$id_usuario}' ";

            $resultado =  $wpdb->get_results( $consulta );
            foreach( $resultado as $fila ){
                $clCliente = $x;
                $clCliente->formateaSalida( $fila );

            }
            return $clCliente;  
        }

        $tabla    = $wpdb->prefix . "mod_usuarios";
        $consulta = "Select * from {$tabla}";

        $resultados = $wpdb->get_results( $consulta );            
        $array = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach( $resultados as $fila ){
            $array[$i] = $x;
            $array[$i]->formateaSalida( $fila );
            $i++;
        }

        return $array;                  
}
```

1. Una variable dentro de un string delimitado por comillas dobles, se interpreta más rápido entre llaves "{$var}".
2. Dado que los dos bloques del condicional terminan con un ***return***, el segundo bloque puede prescindir de quedar incluido dentro de el else.
3. Saco la instanciación de **acClientes()** de los bucles, lo que es bastante costoso, y lo hago sólo una vez, antes del condicional, ya que es una instancia que se va a usar antes o después.

En cuanto a tu problema de redimiento apostaría por el punto 3 o por algo relacionado con tu declaración de la global.

Saludos.

Comment: Tu punto #1 es correcto aunque **siempre hay que tener en cuenta que esas variables DEBEN estar escapadas de cualquier codigo malicioso y/o inyección**