# Optimizar consulta mysql mediante la creación de un índice

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en una base de datos de `mysql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cache(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    md5 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    user TEXT NOT NULL ,
    expires INT NOT NULL ,
    cache_uid INT NOT NULL ,
    task_uid INT NOT NULL,
    task_image_cuality INT NOT NULL
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

En una parte del programa (PHP), necesito obtener todos los registros que coinciden con un usuario determinado.

```
$user = 'user_name';

$res = DBHelper::Query(
        "SELECT 
            id FROM cache
        WHERE 
            user='{$user}'
        "
        , $error);
```

`DBHelper` es una encapsulación de las funciones mysql nativas de `PHP`, que funciona correctamente. El problema consiste en que tengo alrededor de 3 000 000 de entradas en la tabla y las consultas están demorando demasiado (más de 1 min).

Además sobre la tabla se ejecutan más consultas que operaciones de inserción.

¿ Cómo puedo lograr que mi consulta se ejecute de manera rápida y eficiente ?

Comment: Te puede servir también `EXPLAIN` para verificar lo que ocurre en tus consultas y optimizar la BD. Ver: **[MySQL: ¿Para qué sirve `EXPLAIN` en una consulta y cómo interpretar los resultados obtenidos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53779/29967)**

Answer (score 0):

Creando un índice en el campo `user` se logra que la consulta tenga un tiempo proporcional a `O(1)`. Las operaciones de inserción tardarán un tiempo proporcional a O(log n). Siendo n la cantidad de registros en la tabla.

Creando el indice:

```
CREATE INDEX index_user ON cache(user)
```