# Obtener ultimo registro en select filtrando por id y ultima fecha de ingreso MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer un `query` el cual me trae el ultimo registro dentro de una tabla donde dichos registros suelen o van a estar repetidos.

Esta sería mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que busco lograr es hacer un `query` donde filtre por fecha y `id_producto`

Comment: ¿Cuáles serían los resultados esperados de tu consulta? Las soluciones que te dan sólo va a devolver 1 registro, pero por el enunciado de la pregunta parece que se deberían devolver 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo dos posibilidades de consulta.

Según los índices que tengas establecidos en tu tabla, puedes elegir una u otra.

Puedes probar lo que ocurre colocando `EXPLAIN` antes de cada cláusula `SELECT`.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/TDLN10060)**</kbd>

### Opción 1

```
SELECT  
    producto_id, MAX(fecha) AS fecha
FROM 
    producto_20170927
WHERE 
    producto_id = 8
;
```

---

### Opción 2

```
SELECT  
    a.producto_id, a.fecha
FROM    
    producto_20170927 a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  producto_id, MAX(fecha) fecha_max
            FROM    producto_20170927
            GROUP BY producto_id
        ) b ON a.producto_id = b.producto_id AND
                a.fecha = b.fecha_max
 WHERE 
     a.producto_id=8
 ;
```

### Resultado

En ambos casos el resultado es el mismo:

```
producto_id      fecha
8                15.09.2017 21:00:00
```

---

Sobre el uso de `EXPLAIN` para evaluar el funcionamiento de las consultas:

- [MySQL: ¿Para qué sirve EXPLAIN en una consulta y cómo interpretar los resultados obtenidos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53779/29967)

Answer (score 3):

Prueba asi:

```
SELECT * FROM TUTABLA WHERE id_producto = 8 AND fecha_creacion = (SELECT MAX(fecha_creacion) from TUTABLA)
```

Bueno, aqui se aplica una subconsulta para traer la ultima fecha de el id del producto que quieres mostrar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus aportes pude resolver con esta pequeña linea que me fue de mucha utilidas

Comment: ¡En hora buena que lograste resolver!

Comment: Muchas gracias x esta pequeña lineaq me fue de mucha utilidad

Comment: con gusto @Rosamariamartinez