# codeigniter traer el numero de datos registrados en mi base

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, subconsultas

hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar quiero traer la cantidad de datos registrados en mi base
**modelo**

```
    public function countTotalUsers()
{
    $sql = "SELECT *FROM usuarios";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

**controlador**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("User_model");

}
public function index()
{
    $this->data['total_products'] = $this->User_model->countTotalUsers();

    $this->load->view('base_site/head');
    $this->load->view('side/ver');
    $this->load->view('dashboardhome/dashboard');
    $this->load->view('base_site/footer');
    $this->load->view('base_site/scripts');
}
```

**vista **

```
              <h3><?php echo $total_products ?></h3>
```

me muestra este error en mi vista
*A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Undefined variable $total_products

Filename: dashboardhome/dashboard.php

Line Number: 32

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\application\views\dashboardhome\dashboard.php
Line: 32
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\application\controllers\dashboardhome\Dashboard.php
Line: 16
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_onc*

[tomando esta linea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105328/obtener-ultimo-registro-en-select-filtrando-por-id-y-ultima-fecha-de-ingreso-mys?rq=1)

Comment: me muestra este error en la vista  A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Undefined variable $total_products

Filename: dashboardhome/dashboard.php

Line Number: 32

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\application\views\dashboardhome\dashboard.php
Line: 32
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\application\controllers\dashboardhome\Dashboard.php
Line: 16
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_onc

Comment: Estás definiendo los datos con `$this->data['total_products']`, ¿cómo los envías a la vista?

Comment: <h3><?php echo $total_products ?></h3>

Answer (score 1):

lo que pasa esque no estas enviando la data a tu vista
esta linea.

`$this->load->view('dashboardhome/dashboard');`

deberia ser asi

`$this->load->view('dashboardhome/dashboard', $this->data);`

Comment: gracias me sirvio