# Cual consulta es mas rapida?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buen día.

Necesito hacer un update a una tabla (tabla a) de 50000 registros desde una tabla (tabla b) de 200000 registros donde busco en la tabla b todos los registros que concuerden con la tabla a.

Tengo estas dos consultas:

```
UPDATE data_0_pagos a
INNER JOIN asgto_datos_ins b ON a.c_cliente = b.c_cliente
SET a.cnt_proc = 1
WHERE
a.c_cliente = b.c_cliente
```

ó

```
UPDATE data_0_pagos a
INNER JOIN asgto_datos_ins b ON a.c_cliente = b.c_cliente
SET a.cnt_proc = 1
```

Lo único que modifico es con el `where` y sin el `where`.

Hago una consulta donde quiero ver los registros que concuerden en ambas tablas y me muestre el `cliente` y el `cnt.proc`:

```
SELECT
data_0_pagos.c_cliente,
data_0_pagos.cnt_proc
FROM
data_0_pagos
INNER JOIN asgto_datos_ins ON asgto_datos_ins.c_cliente = data_0_pagos.c_cliente
WHERE
asgto_datos_ins.c_cliente = data_0_pagos.c_cliente
```

Esta consulta tarda aproximadamente 10000 segundos, entonces quisiera saber si existe alguna alternativa para que sea más rápida la actualización.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu manejador de base de datos?

Comment: utilizamos mysql,

Comment: 50,000 y/o 200,000 registros no son nada para una base de datos bien indexada y optimizada. Revisa al respecto lo planteado en esta pregunta: **[MySQL: ¿Para qué sirve EXPLAIN en una consulta y cómo interpretar los resultados obtenidos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53779/29967)**. En cuanto a las dos consultas, el `WHERE` no es necesario, porque hace exactamente lo mismo que el `JOIN`.