# Consulta lenta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

si pudieran echarme una mano. Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta para obtener un conteo de registros que se encuentran en la tabla activado que pertenecen al punto de venta 2 y a la vez el total de sus registros en número, pero tarda hasta **45 segundos** en responder por la cantidad de información. ¿Hay una manera más eficiente de hacerlo? Gracias

[image: Diagrama SQL]

```
SELECT cr.nombre, (SELECT COUNT(n.id)
    FROM numero n
    INNER JOIN carrier c ON c.id = n.carrier_id
    INNER JOIN cliente cl ON cl.id = n.cliente_id
    INNER JOIN clave_cliente cc ON cc.cliente_id = cl.id
    WHERE c.id = cr.id
    AND cc.puntoVenta_id = 2
    GROUP BY cr.nombre) AS total, 
    (SELECT COUNT(a.id)
    FROM numero n
    INNER JOIN activado a ON a.numero_id = n.id
    INNER JOIN carrier c ON c.id = n.carrier_id
    INNER JOIN cliente cl ON cl.id = n.cliente_id
    INNER JOIN clave_cliente cc ON cc.cliente_id = cl.id
    WHERE c.id = cr.id
    AND cc.puntoVenta_id = 2
    GROUP BY cr.nombre) AS activados
FROM carrier cr
WHERE cr.activo = TRUE;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es imposible contestarte sin ver el explain plan y los datos. No se puede saber que es lo que hace que sea lento. Estas haciendo un select adentro del group by, eso puese que la lentifique un poco...

Comment: podrías poner ejemplos de como te muestra actualmente la información en la tabla de la consulta

Comment: Pon delante de tu consulta la palabra `EXPLAIN ` y revisa los resultados. Te dará muchas pistas sobre posibles problemas con los índices, etc. Puedes consultar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53779/29967) para entender mejor la forma en la que funciona `EXPLAIN`. Te puede ayudar mucho a determinar dónde puede estar el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamentablemente ya estoy saliendo, pero tu problema está en que colocas las subconsultas en el SELECT, con lo cual se ejecutan por cada registro de la tabla `carrier` cuyo campo `activo` sea TRUE.

Es decir, si tiene 10 registros activos, la subconsulta que te da el campo total y la subconsulta que te da el campo activados se ejecutan 10 veces. Si hay 100, se ejecutan 100 y así sucesivamante.

Prueba usar consultas/tablas derivadas, es decir, utilizar tus subconsultas como si fueran Tablas y hacer un JOIN con la tabla Carrier.
Algo como esto:

```
SELECT 
  cr.nombre, 
  t.total as total, 
  a.total as activados 
FROM carrier cr 
  inner join 
    -- primera subconsulta
   (SELECT ci.id, COUNT(n.id) as total 
    FROM numero n 
      INNER JOIN carrier c ON c.id = n.carrier_id 
      INNER JOIN cliente cl ON cl.id = n.cliente_id 
      INNER JOIN clave_cliente cc ON cc.cliente_id = cl.id 
    WHERE 
      --c.id = cr. AND 
      cc.puntoVenta_id = 2 
    GROUP BY 
      cr.nombre
  ) AS t on t.id = cr.id 
  inner join 
    -- segunda subconsulta
   (SELECT 
      c.id, 
      COUNT(a.id) as total 
    FROM 
      numero n 
      INNER JOIN activado a ON a.numero_id = n.id 
      INNER JOIN carrier c ON c.id = n.carrier_id 
      INNER JOIN cliente cl ON cl.id = n.cliente_id 
      INNER JOIN clave_cliente cc ON cc.cliente_id = cl.id 
    WHERE 
        --c.id = cr.id AND  
        cc.puntoVenta_id = 2 
    GROUP BY 
      cr.nombre
  ) AS a on a.id = cr.id 
WHERE 
  cr.activo = TRUE;
```

A ambas subconsultas hice que devuelvan el carrier.id aparte de su total. A la primera le dí el alias **t** y a la segunda el alias **a**.

No tengo tiempo de probarlo pero espero que te sirva.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Me fue de muchísima ayuda, me redujo el tiempo hasta 9 segundos :D te debo una cerveza

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema es la construcción de la consulta, de lo que puedo decirte que sin duda el uso de las subconsultas como columnas y como parte del `group by` muchas veces un cuello de botella importante. De lo que puedo entender de tu código, lo que buscas podrías resolverlo así:

```
SELECT  c.nombre,
        COUNT(n.id) AS total
    FROM carrier c
    INNER JOIN numero n ON c.id = n.carrier_id
    INNER JOIN cliente cl ON cl.id = n.cliente_id
    INNER JOIN clave_cliente cc ON cc.cliente_id = cl.id
    WHERE   cc.puntoVenta_id = 2
            and c.activo = TRUE
    GROUP BY c.nombre
```

Para optimizaciones más profundas habría que conocer los índices y el explain plan.