# Consulta anidada Mysql o left Join tarda demasiado

Tags: mysql, join

Tengo esta base de datos, necesitaria hacer una consulta y traer todos los campos de la tabla dbfs donde el registro haya sido cargado en un tiempo determinado por un usuario determinado (identificado por el numero de DNI) y que pertenezca al mismo numero de factura.. ademas de eso debo seleccionar de la tabla temporal los honorarios, gastos, material, y total donde el num de solicitud y el codigo de nomenclador me coincidan con los registrso de la tabla dbfs.. intente de varias maneras, la siguiente query es la mas veloz y tarda alrededor de 30seg

```
SELECT dbfs.*,temporal.HONORARIOS, temporal.GASTOS, temporal.MATERIAL, 
       temporal.TOTAL 
FROM dbfs 
LEFT JOIN temporal ON dbfs.cod_nom = temporal.COD_NOMEN 
AND dbfs.NUM_SOL = temporal.NUM_SOL 
WHERE dbfs.dni_user='$dni' AND dbfs.timestamp_carga='$carga' 
AND dbfs.num_factura='$fact';
```

[image: Diseño de la BBDD**texto en negrita**]

Adjunto el explain:

[image: explain]

Disculpen, aun no se bien como dar formato a las preguntas, gracias!

Comment: Como punto de partida te recomiendo que uses `EXPLAIN`. Se trata de poner esa palabra delante de la consulta y revisar la cantidad de filas que lee en cada tabla. Será un primer indicador para ayudarte a decidir qué indices debes mejorar o agregar y en qué tablas (generalmente, las tablas no indexadas o mal indexadas traen todas las filas o varios miles o millones de filas lo cual ralentiza bastante). Para más detalles sobre `EXPLAIN` puedes consultar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53779/29967) y sus respuestas.

Comment: gracias, tu repuesta sirvio de mucha ayuda para encaminarme... lo resolvi generando una nuevo campo combinando los dos de la condicion y usandolo como indice :D