# Consulta Mysql muy lenta con inner join on like concat campo

Tags: mysql

estoy haciendo una consulta en la base de datos, una consulta entre dos tablas, unidas por un inner join, lo cual el ON es sobre la misma tabla a la q la uno, y le aplico o like concat  para buscar la coincidencia de caracter.

esta es mi consulta

```
  SELECT n.guia, n.telefono_uno,r.reemplazar_por, r.sin_15,
  r.caracteres, r.empresa, r.servicio,r.modalidad,
    r.localidad from normalizacion_telefonos_validar n
    inner join referencia_completa r ON n.telefono_uno
     LIKE CONCAT('%', r.sin_15, '%') WHERE n.telefono_uno 
      IS NOT NULL AND n.telefono_uno != '0'  GROUP BY n.guia;
```

el problema aqui es que mi consulta dura 1 minuto y 30 segundas. Las tablas estan bien indexadas

la tabla referecia_completa, tiene el indice en la columna sin_15, y la tabla normalizacion_validar_telefonos tiene el indice en telefono_uno.

Sera que la consulta en si es muy lenta y no hay manera de optimizarla? Les agradeceria una guia, gracias

aca les comparto el plan de ejecucion [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes crear una función indexada que te haga el concat, así ese like debería ser más rápido. El problema es que de por si el like es lento más que primero se tiene que ejecutar el concat por cada registro.. Cuántas filas tienen esas tablas ahora??, Coloca el plan de ejecución del query

Comment: Analiza tu consulta con `EXPLAIN`, si la consulta es lenta puede ser debido a problemas con los índices en alguna tabla, revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53779/29967) sobre la utilidad de `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: ahi lo subi bro @zerocool

Comment: Sigues con esto? estuve muy ocupado. Alli se ve que se está haciendo un full scan ya que no tiene manera de hacerlo más rápido por la concatenación que estás haciendo. Por qué necesitas el like? eso para ver un poco si se puede cambiar.

Comment: si, la deje asi porque es necesario que sea un like '%string%', porque yo ingreso una serie de string, que son n.telefono. y ese n.telefono tiene que tener un patron, el patron es sin_15, asi, cuando se cumpla esa condicion, el n.telefono, es valido.