# Aclaración de busquedas de MYSQL

Tags: mysql

empecé a jugar con una tabla y alterar valores e índices, pero me saltó una duda.

¿Por que existe tanta diferencia al buscar diferentes tipos de columnas?

Estaba haciendo una simple consulta

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE col1 = "dato1" AND col2 = "dato2"
```

Y esta consulta, en una BD de 1200K registros, demora 10 segundos, una barbaridad.

Ahora, existe una columna, que es PK, que crea una clave, mezclando dato1 y dato, quedaria como:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE clave = "dato1_dato2"
```

Y esta consulta demora 0,0052s !! Por que tanta diferencia, si ni siquiera son tantos registros ?

Ahora, entiendo que las PK e indices estan para eso... pero mi pregunta es... ¿ PORQUE ocurre eso ?
Y si hay modo de sacarle aún más partido a estas cosas.

Comment: Es un tema completo: **Tuning** (en inglés). En español lo he visto -pocas veces- traducido como *Afinación de Consultas* o *Puesta a Punto* u *Optimización de Desempeño* de la Base de Datos.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` te ayudará a entender lo que ocurre. Te dirá por ejemplo cuántas filas se están leyendo en cada una de las consultas y podrás mejorar los índices si fuera preciso. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53779/29967) y sus respuestas, que te ayudarán a usar `EXPLAIN` para mejorar el rendimiento de tus tablas.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo he mirado con el consejo de bianchi, pero nunca entiendo que sucede XD

Answer (score 1):

Talvez tiene algo que ver con el tipo de base de datos que utilizas:

**MyISAM** es más rápido que **InnoDB**, puesto que en las consultas **InnoDB** se debe de comprobar la integridad referencial de los datos, mientras que en **MyISAM** eso no es necesario, ya que esa propiedad no es soportada por este motor de almacenamiento.

También habría que ver si estás utilizando ***Primary Key*** o ***Index*** en los campos del select.

Y no es recomendable utilizar `select *`, es mejor indicar los campos con los que se trabajará.

Comment: La integridad referencial afectaría `INSERT`, `UPDATE` y `DELETE` mas no `SELECT`.

Comment: Es mejor seleccionar campos que todo ? wow nunca lo imagine. Y si, indexes y PK estan siendo aplicadas.