# Consulta MySQL es lenta con varios INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

muy buen día, tengo un pequeño problema y es que mi consulta en MySQL dentro de la herramienta gestora de la base de datos (HeidiSQL) tanto en la parte de front-end, es lenta y me causa molestia, ya que solo tengo 3 registros de prueba en la base de datos y me genera mucha demora, la consulta a continuación demora entre 10 y 13 segundos... MUCHO TIEMPO!

Por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar.

```
SELECT 
   m.idmodulo1 idmodulo1, m.codigo_evento codigo_evento,
   m.fecha_notificacion fecha_notificacion, m.semana_notificacion
   semana_notificacion, m.codigo_prestador codigo_prestador,
   m.nombre1 nombre1, m.nombre2 nombre2, m.apellido1 apellido1,
   m.apellido2 apellido2, td.codigo codigo_td, td.nombre tipo_documento,
   m.documento documento, m.fecha_nacimiento nacimiento,
   sex.nombre sexo, e.nombre eps, e.codigo codigo_eps,
   m.nombre_evento nombre_evento, ic.nombre investigacion_campo,
   a.nombre acta_seguimiento, al.nombre alerta_epidemiologica,
   info24.nombre informe_24, infoc.nombre informe_cierre,
   br.nombre brote, fa.nombre fallecido, auto.nombre autosia,
   hc1.nombre hc1, hc2.nombre hc2, esv.nombre estado_evento,
   m.observaciones observaciones, u.documento u_documento,
   ba.nombre bac, ua.nombre unidad_analisis, acta_ua.nombre acta_ua,
   ra.nombre requiere_ajuste, m.fecha_reporte, m.hora_reporte
FROM modulo1 m
INNER JOIN tipo_documento td ON m.fk_tipo_documento = td.idtipo_documento
INNER JOIN sexo sex ON m.fk_sexo = sex.idsexo
INNER JOIN eps e ON m.fk_eps = e.ideps
INNER JOIN investigacion_campo ic ON
   m.fk_investigacion_campo = ic.idinvestigacion_campo
INNER JOIN acta_seguimiento a ON m.fk_acta_seguimiento = a.idacta_seguimiento 
INNER JOIN alerta_epidemiologica al ON 
   m.fk_alerta_epidemiologica = al.idalerta_epidemiologica 
INNER JOIN informe_24_horas info24 ON m.fk_informe24 = info24.idinforme_24_horas 
INNER JOIN informe_cierre infoc ON
   m.fk_informe_cierre = infoc.idinforme_cierre 
INNER JOIN brote br ON m.fk_brote = br.idbrote 
INNER JOIN bac ba ON m.fk_bac = ba.idbac
INNER JOIN fallecido fa ON m.fk_fallecido = fa.idfallecido
INNER JOIN autopsia_verbal auto ON m.fk_autopsia_verbal = auto.idautopsia_verbal 
INNER JOIN unidad_analisis ua ON
   m.fk_unidad_analisis = ua.idunidad_analisis 
INNER JOIN acta_unidad_analisis acta_ua ON
   m.fk_acta_ua = acta_ua.idacta_analisis 
INNER JOIN hc_nivel1 hc1 ON m.fk_hc_nivel1 = hc1.idhc_nivel1 
INNER JOIN hc_nivel2 hc2 ON m.fk_hc_nivel2 = hc2.idhc_nivel2 
INNER JOIN requiere_ajuste ra ON m.fk_ajuste = ra.idrequiere_ajuste 
INNER JOIN estado_evento esv ON
   m.fk_estado_evento = esv.idestado_evento 
INNER JOIN usuario u ON m.fk_usuario = u.documento

WHERE u.documento = '65236452'
```

Si alguien sabe como mejorar esa consulta, le agradezco.

Comment: ¿La consulta arroja tres filas o arroja más filas? Si tienes posibilidad de probarla directamente desde la consola hazlo y verifica si allí también es lenta (la lentitud no siempre es debido a un problema en las tablas, puede ser la conexión, el servidor, la interfaz...). Analiza también la consulta poniendo delante de ella `EXPLAIN` (revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53779/29967) para más detalles sobre esto). Si sigues sin encontrar el problema, agrega a la pregunta todos los `CREATE TABLE` de tus tablas a ver si hay algo raro.

Comment: Solo tengo esos tres registros, y digamos que las tablas están bien creadas, de hecho es la única consulta larga la cual me genera mucho tiempo en ejecutarse.

Comment: Lo que preguntaba es si la tabla arroja tres filas o arroja más filas (aunque **existan** sólo tres filas, puede arrojar por ejemplo 9, ó 27 ó 33 ó 99999999 filas porque los JOIN o los datos estén mal). Entonces ¿cuántas filas arroja la consulta? era mi pregunta. Luego, la afirmación *las tablas están bien creadas* debe ser demostrado. Por *bien creada*  entiéndase *bien diseñada*, con los índices correctos y demás. Todo eso sólo podrá verificarse si muestras los `CREATE TABLE` de cada una. Ante consultas lentas debes ir descartando causas, empezando por los escenarios donde las ejecutas.

Comment: Entiendo, de momento me muestra tres registros, pues en esa tabla solo tengo tres registros, si me mostrará más lo afirmaría, pero solo me muestra los tres registros que están en esa tabla. Mi pregunta es si por ejemplo debo de llamar a los índices en algún lado de mi consulta SQL, o si los indicen en todas las tablas si tienen la misma llave foránea deberían de llamarme igual.

Comment: Porque no se, si me puedas colaborar mediante meet o algo así por el estilo y poder solucionar ese pequeño problema... Gracias.

Comment: podrías agregarte un ejemplo de tus datos en http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Gracias, ya solucione el problema.